# union gives one row with null collection data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-9

I am using this type of query in Laravel model this query is given right result when I don't use any search query or get minimum one data but when I search data using Asin or sku this query given one correct row and one null row or if don't get any data then also given null row :-

```
   $productQuery = self::select('amazon_order_reports.*',
    )
    ->join('dashboard_order_profits', function($query) {
        $query->on('dashboard_order_profits.order_id','amazon_order_reports.id');
    })
    ->with(['amazonProduct' => function($query2){
            $query2->select('id', 'main_image', 'title', 'asin', 'sku', 'price','cogs', 
    'units_at_amazon', 'updated_at');
    }])
    ->whereIn('amazon_order_reports.id', [1,2,3,4,5])
    ->whereBetween('amazon_order_reports.order_date', [$tabStartDate, $tabEndDate]);

    $refundQuery = self::select('amazon_order_reports.*',
        DB::raw("SUM(item_price) as total_product_sales"),
        DB::raw("SUM(quantity) as total_product_units"),
    )
    ->join('dashboard_order_profits', function($query) {
        $query->on('dashboard_order_profits.order_id','amazon_order_reports.id');
    })
    ->with(['amazonProduct' => function($query2){
            $query2->select('id', 'main_image', 'title', 'Asin', 'sku', 'price','cogs', 
   'units_at_amazon', 'updated_at');
    }])
    ->where(function ($query) use ($params){
        $query->where('product_name', '%' . $params['search'] . '%');
        $query->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $params['search'] . '%');
        $query->orWhere('asin', 'LIKE', '%' . $params['search'] . '%');
    })
    ->whereIn('amazon_order_reports.id', $amazonOrderReportIdsArr)
    ->whereBetween('dashboard_order_profits.refund_posted_date', [$tabStartDate, 
     $tabEndDate]);

    $result = $productQuery->union($refundQuery)->groupBy( 
       'amazon_order_reports.product_id');
```

but this query always gives one extra null row collection.